How can I identify all network traffic that matches a push or commit to github.com?
Say I have thousands of users on the same corporate network making millions of network requests/transactions.
Say some of them are committing or pushing code to some repo, public or private, on github.com.
However they are committing or pushing the code -- command line, IDE, etc. -- I'm assuming the computer makes some type of PUSH request to some GitHub URL/API. Is that right?
Could I dump all destinations of all network requests and then filter on the commits/pushes to GH?

Git has its own wire protocol, but in practice that protocol is wrapped in HTTPS or SSH requests for requests over the public Internet. Those two protocols implement both encryption and authentication/authorization methods that plain git:// doesn't support. Those two methods also wrap pulls, fetches, clones, and ls-remote calls, in addition to pushes. GitHub's API is a separate thing, which is normally used for controlling repositories (set up, change permissions, file issues, etc.) rather than receiving commits.
If you're only interested in the number of connections to GitHub in a particular time period, then you should be able to log traffic between your network and GitHub's IP ranges (https://api.github.com/meta has the up-to-date list) on destination ports 22, 80, and 443. This will include all requests, but it won't tell you whether a particular request was a push or pull or something on the UI or something else, and it also won't tell you whether a particular request was successful.
If you want to know specifically how many pushes happen in a time period, then you'll have to route all the traffic through an inspecting proxy of some kind. (You'll probably also want to prohibit connections to github.com:22 and ssh.github.com:443, because SSH proxying can get complicated.) This approach is a lot more work to set up and to maintain, but it can tell you how many pushes happen, as well as whether those were successful.

We already block 22 so that's fine. I need to identify users who committed/pushed code. What would the inspect proxy look for?

You also need to block connections to ssh.github.com port 443. GitHub set that hostname and port combo up for people who want to use SSH but whose local networks or ISPs block port 22.

As for what to look for, during a push, the Git client will send a GET to the repo URL with /info/refs?service=git-receive-pack appended to the end, and then a POST to the repo URL with /git-receive-pack appended to the end. (The GET establishes what the remote knows, and the POST uploads the difference. A successful push needs both.) You should be able to break it down into success/failure by watching HTTP status codes.
